# Why routing based on ui-router-ng2 doesn't work with basehref?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an application where the routing is based on ui-router-ng2. In development environment it works as it is expected. The url is

> http://localhost:4200

When I deploy it to production then the routing doesn't work. In this case the url is

> http://prodenv.com/stuff/ui.spa/

The code runs in prod generated by angular-cli using the following command:

> ng build --prod --base-href \"stuff/ui.spa/\"

The application loads fine, only the routing doesn't work. It overwrites the url, but other parts of the routing description are not executed, e.g.: value resolving via routing doesn't work ( I pass through value to the components, and I get data from DB about what to display).

I know it is a silly mistake I made, but I cannot find it.

Thanks

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/ui-router/ng2/issues/56 looks like it will be fixed in next release

Comment: Thanks, At the moment I'm playing with Angular2 Router and outlets.